# Multivariable Calculus. Help o how to integrate and To prove a Rotational property

Tags: multivariable-calculus, curves, multiple-integral, stokes-theorem

I've got a couple of doubts in the following excercises. Sorry if somethings wrong or hard to understand in my writing, I'm non-native speaker.

3. Calculate de integral of the function:

$$f(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\exp(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-r)$$

over the set $A=({(x,y)\in R^2| 0 \leqslant x^2+y^2\leqslant r})$ for $r>0$

I've performed a variable change to cilindrical coordinates so

$\int \sqrt{x^2+y^2}e^{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-r}\, dx\,dy = \int \sqrt{r^2} e^{\sqrt{r^2}-r'} r\, dr\, d\theta$ considering $r \ne r'$
Am I I getting this done by the right way, is there anything that I'm not considering?

8. Let $\vec{F}:\Omega\subset R^3 \rightarrow R^3$ class $C^{1}$. Prove that the surface integral of $\nabla \times \vec{F}$ over $\Sigma$ its equal $0$, where $\Sigma \subset \Omega$ it's a sphere (which centre not necessary in $\Omega$) and parameterization of $\Sigma$ it's normal outside,

I've got no clue on how to perform this proof, I've tested performing over Stokes Theorem but not really getting somewhere.
Any ideas or even the proof? It's the bonus of my last evaluation on my course of multivariable integral calculus.

Comment: A few remarks about notation/typesetting, in other words, LaTeX-tips. Inside a formula TeX ignores whitespace. To add a small space between, e.g. the $dx$ and $dy$ you can add a thinspace by inserting `\,`. Click the edit-button to see how I used it. Also, $exp^t$ is meaningless. It is either $\exp(t)$ or $e^t$. The former notation was "invented" to write $e^{\text{something complicated}}$ in-line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $r$ is doing double duty lets lets use $\rho$ as the radius in the coordinate system and $R$ as the radius of the cylinder.

$x = \rho \cos \theta\\
y = \rho \sin \theta\\
0\le\rho \le R$

$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{R} \rho^2e^{\rho-R}\ d\rho\ d\theta\\
2\pi(e^{\rho-R})(\rho^2-2\rho + 2)|_0^R\\
2\pi(R^2 - 2R + 2 - 2e^{-R})$

8) 
By the divergence theorem $\iint G\ dS = \iiint \nabla\cdot G \ dS\\
G = \nabla \times F\\
\nabla \cdot G = \nabla \cdot (\nabla \times F) = 0$

Comment: Is it correct the inequality $$0 \leqslant \rho \leqslant R$$ ? Sould'tn it be $$0 \leqslant \rho^2 \leqslant R$$ due to the coordinates change in the set A

Comment: You are right, if $0\le x^2 + y^2 \le r$ then $0\le \rho^2 \le r$ or $0\le \rho \le \sqrt r$  However that is an unsusual construction.  Before making that change, make sure that the constraint is not in fact $0\le x^2 + y^2 \le r^2$

Comment: I'm not following the hint for exercise 8, I mean, what properties do I need first in order to apply Gauss theorem?

Comment: You must be integrating over a closed surface.  The surface must be compact and piece-wise smooth.  The surface of a sphere qualifies.